# Loop through Workbook doing the same process

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through an excel workbook to create the same pivot table on each sheet, yet each sheet contains different data in the same columns. The pivot table works, but the loop stops after completing the first worksheet.

Does anyone have recommendations on getting the loop to run through all the worksheets?

```
Sub PivotTableLoop()

Dim FinalRow            As Long
Dim DataSheet           As String
Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim DataRng             As Range
Dim TableDest           As Range
Dim ws                  As Worksheet
Dim wb                  As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
DataSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'Beginning of Loop
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

'set data range for Pivot Table
Set DataRng = Sheets(DataSheet).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(FinalRow, 8))  ' conversion of R1C1:R & FinalRow & C8

'set range for Pivot table placement
Set TableDest = Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(1, 9)  ' conversion of R1C9

Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, DataRng)

'this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(DataSheet).PivotTables("PivotTable4") ' check if "PivotTable4" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then ' "PivotTable4" doesn't exist >> create it

'create a new Pivot Table in "PivotTable4" sheet
Set PvtTbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(DataSheet).PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=TableDest, TableName:="PivotTable4")

With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Document Type")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Accounting Event")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With

With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Document Number")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With
PvtTbl.AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
"PivotTable4").PivotFields("Amount"), "Sum of Amount", xlSum

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
PvtTbl.PivotFields("Document Type").ShowDetail _
    = False
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
PvtTbl.CompactLayoutRowHeader = _
    "JIFMS Document Types"
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).Range("A1").Select
PvtTbl.PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
PvtTbl.DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
    "Sum of Amount").Caption = "JIFMS Sum of Amounts"
ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Range("A1").Select
Else  

'just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
PvtTbl.RefreshTableenter code here

End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to **indent your code**. Reading code when the contents of all code blocks are in column 1 makes one's head spin. Code that's hard to read is code that's hard to debug.

Get VBE add-ins. If you're using 32-bit Office, you can use *Smart Indenter* to do it for you. If you're on 64-bit Office you can use the latest MZ-Tools ($$$ I think), or the free and open-source [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (which, *disclaimer*, I'm heavily involved with) - v2.x (still beta) includes most of *Smart Indenter*'s features.

Also get rid of the annoying and useless line continuations such as this one:

> ```
> PvtTbl.PivotFields("Document Type").ShowDetail _
>     = False
> ```

/rant

---

You're not setting `PvtTbl` back to `Nothing` after the first iteration, so the entire `If...End If` block will not run after the reference has been assigned once, presumably in the first iteration.

By extracting the body of the loop into its own procedure (and thus having `PvtTbl` essentially scoped to the body of the loop), you eliminate the problem and enhance your code's readability. This operation is known as an "extract method" refactoring.

You're also iterating all worksheets in the active workbook, but you're not using `ws` anywhere in the body of the loop, so everything works off the active sheet... which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Hey Mat, thanks for the response. Still fairly new the VBA. So really putting together some choppy macro's at this point based on what I am finding throughout SO and books. I will try to put those fixes in and hopefully get it to run.

Comment: Alright, I am lost at this point. I understand what you mean when you say the PvtTbl is set back to Nothing. The script knows that the PvtTbl exists in the first sheet and runs the refresh statement instead of apply the body to the next sheet. I am having trouble with the extract method refactoring and how to make it reference.